# How do I open a file inside a Mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-handling

I would like to open a file inside the bundle by clicking on a button, using the default Mac Os app to open the selected file. For instance it could be a PDF file bundled with the app to be opened in Preview, an MP3 to be opened in iTunes.

Actually I have to install a screensaver in Preference Pane, but I think the approach is the same.

NSWorkspace approach does work (even for screensavers which are actually packages, not files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AppKit's `NSWorkspace`:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/path/to/your/file"];
```